# jquery does not work on loaded html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm appending HTML tags from html file to body using jQuery.After I loaded html tags I am loading JS file that doing something on html tags.jQuery does not work on loaded html but when I putting html tags statically on page jQuery working on it right.

I use this code to append html tags to body 
What's the problem ?

 [Its](http://jsfiddle.net/Zew3H/) my target html tags

```
  function DisplayLoginPanel() {
        $('Body').load('Resources/HTMLContents/Login.htm');
        LoadNewScript("Resources/OtherTools/js/slide.js");
    }
    function LoadNewScript(ScriptPath) {
        $.getScript(ScriptPath, function () {
            alert("Script loaded and executed.");

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then you need to add the `LoadNewScript()` function inside a `complete` event for the `.load()` function. Like this:

```
function DisplayLoginPanel() {
$('Body').load('Resources/HTMLContents/Login.htm', function() {
  LoadNewScript("Resources/OtherTools/js/slide.js");
});
}
```

The reason for this is that when you initiate the `load()` your javascript keeps going forward. It doesn't wait for the login.html to be loaded and as such, the `LoadNewScript` is called before the html has been added.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more details.

Comment: Wow.. you are right thank you. would you please explain the matter ?